# Why does Sleep(); function skip Label -> Text commands?

Tags: winforms, command-line-interface

In my Programming I have made two Attack logs (they are labels) which display things that happen during a battle... But whenever I run the code, both labels skip all previous code and display the last thing that It was told to display...

```
this -> EnemyAttackLog -> Text = "[Enemy Attack Log]   " + EName + " Attacked!!";
             Sleep(500);
             damage = rnd4 -> Next(-2,3) + EnemyA;
             if (D > EnemyA)
             {
                 damage = rnd4 -> Next(3,6);
                 this -> AttackLog -> Text = "[Attack Log]    Your Armor Reduced the Damage!";
             }
             Sleep(500);
             this -> EnemyAttackLog -> Text = "[Enemy Attack Log]   " + EName + " did " + damage + " Damage";
             Hp -= damage;
             this -> HealthBar -> Value = Hp;
             Sleep(800);
             damage = rnd4 -> Next(-2,3) + A;
             if (EnemyD > A)
             {
                 damage = rnd4 -> Next(3,6);
                 this -> EnemyAttackLog -> Text = "[Enemy Attack Log]    " + EName + "'s armor reduced damage!";
             }
             Sleep(1500);
             this -> AttackLog -> Text = "[Attack Log]   " + Name + " did " + damage + " Damage";
             EnemyHp -= damage;
             this -> EnemyHealth -> Value = EnemyHp;
```

If this did what i thought it would do, It would display

```
this -> EnemyAttackLog -> Text = "[Enemy Attack Log]   " + EName + " Attacked!!";
```

for Half a second and move on to display the next code for Another half a second, But instead, all it does is wait for ALL the sleep functions (Which added together makes 3300 milliseconds) and THEN displays the text at the very end... which is

```
this -> AttackLog -> Text = "[Attack Log]   " + Name + " did " + damage + " Damage";
```

Why does it skip all previous commands (for the labels text) but STILL waits for 3300 milliseconds?

Comment: Show us code, not logs.

Comment: I may be missing something, but where is the bit that prints the text? Is seems that after sleeping you are assigning a new value to Text.

Comment: @MotoSV since this is winforms the This -> TextBox -> Text = ""; Will automatically print the text onto the windowed application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably down to the fact you are sleeping the UI thread. I've just tried a similar test in C# and I get the same issue. To fix this you will have to call Refresh on the textbox after setting the value.

Another way would be to do the work on a background thread and then marshal the "this->EnemyAttackLog->Text = sometext" code onto the UI thread. This way your UI will stay responsive.